# Discrete or continuous

Tags: probability

The time a commuter must wait at a certain stoplight, given that the stoplight alternates between 60 seconds green and 60 seconds red

I'm leaning more towards discrete since there is a defined interval of 60 seconds, but I can also see how it could also be continuous since the commuter could wait for 1.5 seconds.

Comment: Continuous - you're thinking discrete because the intervals happen to be an integral number of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous, because because time is continuous.